# Does the Oval Office appear in Season 1 of Madam Secretary?

Tags: madam-secretary

Since *Madam Secretary* is a political show about a member of the cabinet, I expected plenty of scenes in the Oval Office. Yet I can't think of a single scene that takes place in the Oval Office. Even when the President is clearly hosting a meeting with Madam Secretary in the White House, it seems to often take place in a room with rectangular corners.

Are there **any** scenes in the **first season** that take place in the Oval Office?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95858/discussion-on-question-by-leventrek-does-the-oval-office-appear-in-season-1-of-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From The Salt Lake Tribune's archives ['Madam Secretary' star Keith Carradine: 1 of many TV presidents](https://archive.sltrib.com/article.php?id=4403392&itype=CMSID).

> But President Dalton didn't have an Oval Office the first season of "Madam President." As a recurring cast member, Carradine performed his presidential duties in scenes located elsewhere (including White House corridors that actually belonged to Manhattan's Waldorf Astoria hotel).
> His Oval Office set, introduced for Season 2, is appropriately elegant.
> *By Frazier Moore
> The Associated Press
>
>   September 27, 2016 11:18 am*

I can only assume that *"Madam President"* is a typo and should have been *"Madam Secretary"*.